# Merge local non git work to remote git repository

Tags: git, merge, local, rebase

I would like to merge my work from a non git-initiated folder with a remote git repository.

The following works:

```
git init
git add
git commit

git remote add origin [url]
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
git push -u origin master
```

An alternative is :

```
git init
git add
git commit

git remote add origin [url]
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories origin master
git push -u origin master
```

but `--allow-unrelated-histories` is long to write (git's creators do not want to implement a shortcut because "it's a rare case") and I heard it is better to do a rebase than a merge in this case.

Do you know a faster way to do this?

**EDIT**
The long version:

I willingly skipped the workflow part to go straight to the point, but here is my workflow to understand why (I keep in mind your recommended workflow but I am not sure it applies in my case):

- the code of my website is on the ftp
- I work directly on the ftp because it's more convenient for me
- I drag and drop the ftp folder on my desktop and run the git commands to merge my local-ftp changes with my collaborators-GitHub ones.

Why I work directly on the ftp:
- all integrated in my IDE, I can do modifications "on the fly" with one software
- no local server to use
- no transfert from local to ftp to do (unless collaborators made changes on GitHub)
- payable plugins of the website not to my disposition localy so I can't have a proper local testing environment
- I used to work localy but the results were different when I transfered the code to ftp for any reason

I agree this may be "handcrafted" like, but it did the job well since I worked alone on the code. Now there is another person so we put the code on GitHub and I solved the sync problem between our codes with the mentioned git commands. I have write access to the code so I don't have to fork/pull request. I don't need to keep permanently a local repo, so I prefer to wipe it, but if SCM needs me to keep a local repo of all my projetc, I will do, but eh... I don't like it cause I don't need it, that's why I found a solution in my first message.

Do you think I should have a better workflow? Do you think we should work on different branches even for small changes (if it allows to have a cleaner history I will do, cause I like to remain organized and lean, by the way that's why I used rebase and not merge)?

In fact the big background question is: how do large teams sync their GitHub code with their ftp code (and checking the new GitHub code is ok on a test ftp folder before updating the repo and the actual ftp repo) ? Silly question: do they do SCM right from the ftp (how? this would be awesome) ?

I am new to SCM and I am asking myself all these questions...

Comment: If this happens often, why don't you write an alias?

Comment: "`--allow-unrelated-histories` is long to write" so [tab-complete it](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know a faster way to do this?

This is the wrong question to ask.  The right question is: **What drives you to do any work outside of SCM - outside of either a local or remote repo?**

The question of what is the "fastest" way to sync up your work with a remote repo is legitimate, but since you haven't provided any details on your workflow, we can't answer that one for sure.

### I would recommend this workflow instead:

1. If on Github - fork the remote repo if appropriate first
2. Clone the remote repo (or your fork) before doing any work to your local PC, so you can work in a local repo.
3. Create a branch for this feature/output that will be merged in the future
4. Do all your work in the branch, committing and otherwise taking advantage of Git's SCM to create a history and ability to revert changes at any time
5. Push your branch to the remote regularly if others should be able to see the work in-progress for any reason (such as if you ask for help) and to give you a backup.
6. When ready to merge, just issue a pull-request, if appropriate (or in your own fork), and to allow for a code/artifact review; alternatively, just merge into master if that's how this project operates.

There might be some alternate strategies we could recommend with more details, but I think you're making things more complicated then they have to be, especially in terms of the merge vs. rebase question, which must mean that in your remote repo, the only branch is master(!) - are you familar with the Gitflow model of maintaining multiple dev, experiment branches, for example?  Are you familiar with just how easy it is to branch and merge in Git?

**Git was made for distributed source control management - so use it for that!  (i.e. use it locally during development).**

---

### Updated for the longer history added to the question

I think the above will still work fine, if I understand your situation correctly.  I recommend creating a mirror of the Github repo on your local PC, which you always keep there.  You can still do all your changes up on the server through FTP since you say this is more convenient - but I'd be careful with that because then (if I understand right), you are changing live web site.  If that works for your situation (including the dangers of doing so without testing new releases first), then that's fine though.

Given your specific situation I'd try the two ways below - but I'm not 100% sure how Git will interact with the FTP (i.e. hopefully it doesn't refresh the dates on existing files or anything else that causes Git to see them as changed)

1. Keep doing what you are doing - except leave a loco repo on your local PC. This method will just dump your changes as a new commit to master.

   - Make your new changes to the FTP site
   - When ready to add your updates to the repo, do a fetch of the remote server to your local server to pick up any new commits on the remote before pulling down from FTP.
   - Pull your changes down from the FTP into the local repo, just overwriting any existing files. If this works the way I think, then a git status will show only the changed files at this point.
   - Do a `git add .` to add all the changes to the index
   - Commit to master with your changes
   - Push to remote, which should just add your new commit with your new changes to the remote. Small possibility of a conflict if someone else commits between your fetch and push.
   - rinse and repeat
2. Go to a branch strategy. Still keeps a local repo

   - Come up with some branching strategy that everyone on the repo agrees with (sounds like it's just two of you).  In this case I might suggest you just have a separate branch from master, probably just with your name or 'dev', 'web', etc. (something short and easy to type!).
   - Alternately, you could branch for every change, but that sounds like overkill here.
   - Any changes you make to the site, you can pull down from FTP and add/commit to your local branch.
   - Any time you have a commit that you want to merge to master, do a fetch, merge, then pull.
   - **Advantage 1:** You can commit as often as you want to your local repo, which will store a history of any changes, and allow you to revert at any time to a former commit if something goes wrong on the FTP site.
   - **Advantage 2:** Your separate branch will be duplicated on the remote repo so that all parties can see the history of that branch, when merges were done, etc., if the history of issues needs to be tracked.
   - **Advantage 3:** You can still always merge with a pull request from a branch, if desired, which should avoid any conflicts if multiple people are trying to merge (i.e. let the person maintaining the remote decide when to merge it, or open communications if there will be an issue).  In other words, you don't take responsibility for the master branch, you can just live in your side branch.

If none of this looks like it would work for you - I'd try out the other solution I posted as an alternate.  There shouldn't be any need for deleting the local repo each time, so that will even save you a step, I think - or maybe just make it a fetch rather than a clone?

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

"What drives you to do any work outside of SCM?"
The short answer is: because I work on the ftp.

I edited my question to add the details of my workflow. Maybe you could answer again taking this in consideration :)

Comment: @VictorAlexandre I updated the answer with a part 2 based on your edit/update.  I think you can just keep doing what you are doing, but if you switch to using a local repo, then you will have an advantage of being able to branch to test out changes, commit partially complete things without pushing to remote, and all the other things that SCM in general get for you.

Answer (score 0):

I really think my other answer is better, but here is an alternative to do exactly what you asked...

In the parent to your development folder that is not in a repo:

> ```
> > git clone [repo URL]
> > cd [repo name]
> > mv ../[folder name of your stuff] .
> > git add .
> > git commit -m "added my stuff in folder [folder name of your stuff]"
> ```

Essentially, you are cloning the repo **first**, then just moving your development folder into the repo, adding it, and committing it to whatever branch you need to (I assumed master here).

This is maybe a little shorter, probably cleaner - easier to understand since you are adding the items after the repo already exists, so you don't have separate master branches with different histories.

**Edit:** Given the updated history, you can even shorten this more by just FTP'ing down from the web site server directly into the local repo (rather than forcing the `mv` command.

You also could leave the local repo around all the time, and just change the clone into a fetch.